# JSON split value at first space

Tags: javascript, json, split

I'm very new to JSON and I have not found the answer searching. I'm thinking my question is just too simple

I have a simple JSON

```
{   
    "Application":     "The Best Application",
}
```

My goal is to split the value at the first space and store the next word in a variable, which in this case would be the word `Best`

I've tried the following, but it is not working:

```
var json = '{"Application":"The Best Application",}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
var obj2 = obj.result.split(" ");
console.log(obj2.result);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.split()` returns an array and you want to take an item under index `1`. Also note that `JSON.parse()` returns an object and you want to read the value from `Application` key:

```js
var json = '{"Application":"The Best Application"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
var obj2 = obj["Application"].split(" ");
console.log(obj2[1]);
```